# Cannot load image for region

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

Why doesn't JavaFX load my image for region though there is no error?

**HelloApplication.java**

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Region region = new Region();
        region.setId("region");
        Scene scene = new Scene(region,500,500);
        region.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("css.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**css.css**

```
#region {
    -fx-background-image: url('/com/example/demotmp/Asset1.png');
}
```

**My structure file**
[image]

Comment: Does `url('Asset1.png')` work?

Comment: it has error loading image

Comment: I just added the structure of the javafx file

Comment: You have the image file(s) in the wrong location. Images are resources, not Java source files, so they should be under `src/main/resources` (or a subdirectory, i.e., package).

Comment: @Slaw It really works, thank you very much sir